# ASP.NET disable the image button

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="btnRemoveUser" runat="server" CommandName="ApplyRemoval" ImageUrl="~/Images/save.gif" onclick="btnRemoveUser_Click"/>
```

How do I disable the ASP.Net Image button in the btnRemoveUser_Click event ?

I tried following but they are not working :

```
btnRemoveUser.Visible = false;
btnRemoveUser.style.display = 'none';
btnRemoveUser.Attributes["disabled"] = "disabled";
```

Comment: Do you want it disabled or invisible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the image buttons Enable property to false

```
btnRemoveUser.Enabled = false;
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87xh91hb(v=vs.110).aspx for details

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to do it in c# or in jquery? Here is the code for c#:

```
btnRemoveUser.Attributes.Add("disabled", "disabled");
```